# Envoy - Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, envoyproxy

I'm trying to deploy my project using Envoy. I linked my vagrant to a deploybot user on the server, which works perfectly, but when I try to deploy my project I get these errors

```
[deploybot@"Server IP"]: PHP Warning:  require(/home/boost/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/boost/artisan on line 16 [deploybot@"Server IP"]: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
'/home/boost/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share                            /php') in /home/boost/artisan on line 16
```

I've been trying to switch some permissions around, but that didn't seem to work.
Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: either the user you're running as doesn't have read permissions on `/home/boost/bootstrap/autoload.php`, or it doesn't have execute permissions on the directory it's in, or one of its parents. what does `ls -ld /home/boost/bootstrap/autoload.php /home/boost/bootstrap /home/boost /home` show, and what user are you running as?

Comment: I see, it shows permission denied. I'm running the deploybot user on my server.

Comment: need to fix the correct permissions then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running these commands. This will make it so the deploybot will be able to read and write in files.

```
chown -R deploybot directory
chmod -R u+rX directory
```